# ActiveAdmin manage abilities of custom member_action with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I'm working on a rails project with ActiveAdmin, Devise and CanCan.

What I want do is checking ability of custom member_action with cancan. Like this

```
def initialize(admin_user)
  can :read, ModelA
  can [:disable,:reset], ModelA if admin_user.has_edit_ability?
end
```

The second 'can' line doesn't works.

---

Following are related codes in my project. I added two member action in ActiveAdmin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ModelA do
  def member_action :disable, :method => :post do
     ...
  end
  def member_action :reset, :method => :post do
     ...
  end
  ...
  index do
    ...
    actions do |m|
      link_to 'disable', disable_admin_model_a_path(m.id)
      link_to 'reset', reset_admin_model_a_path(m.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The class of admin user is AdminUser.
AdminAbility is defined in admin_user.rb

```
class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(admin_user)
    can :read, ModelA
    can [:disable,:reset], ModelA if admin_user.has_edit_ability?
  end
end
```

---

I realized it may not being supported by ActiveAdmin. I want to know whether I can make it works by adding other codes, or I should check ability of custom member_action in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you should do it manualy, something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ModelA do
  def member_action :disable, :method => :post do
    authorize! :disable, @instance_for_modela
    ...
  end
  def member_action :reset, :method => :post do
    authorize! :reset, @instance_for_modela
     ...
  end
  ...
  index do
    ...
    actions do |m|
      link_to 'disable', disable_admin_model_a_path(m.id) if authorized?(:disable, m)
      link_to 'reset', reset_admin_model_a_path(m.id) if authorized?(:reset, m)
    end
  end
end
```